# How to print PostScript from an iPad programmatically?

Tags: uiview, postscript, airprint

I'm comfortable coding in PostScript, which is a stack-based language for printing on which PDF is based. I'd sure like to be able to generate my PostScript code as a string and then send it to a printer from inside my iPad app.

But is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an iOS developer, and haven't look at AirPrint at all, so this might be a naive comment.  Could you just open up port 9100 and fire the data directly at the IP address of the printer?

Comment: This is the old hacker way. Not sure if it works anymore, either. But +1 for nostalgia.

Answer (score 1):

There ought to be a way to convert PS to PDF by slapping on a header, assuming the PS is simple enough.
Once the file is a PDF, you should be able to convey it to iBooks.